# mapping classes in simple jpa project

Tags: java, jpa, entity, wildfly

I whant to configure a simple JPA project, i using Wildfly 8, and the datasource is configured in standalone.xml.

```
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/postgresql" pool-name="postgreSql" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sell</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgres</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>sell</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
```

in Web project i configure the persistence.xml file like this

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="sellAppPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">              
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/postgresql</jta-data-source>
    <class>br.com.sell.app.orm.Usuario</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

but, when i add a *br.com.sell.app.orm.Usuario* i got a error on project startup, the error indicates a hibernate problem *org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy*, but i don't use hibernate.

```
13:17:50,738 ERROR [org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: br.com.sell.app.orm.Usuario: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:492)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:428)
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

Why i can solve this problem?

the pom.xml file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    br.com.sell.app
    sellApp
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    pom
    sellApp
    Backend rest sell app

```
<modules>
    <module>sellAppEndpoint</module>
    <module>sellAppWeb</module>
    <module>sellAppCors</module>
    <module>sellAppDto</module>
    <module>sellAppOrm</module>
    <module>sellAppJpa</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <!-- para importar pacotes javax.* para o REST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.SP1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: If you "don't use Hibernate" what JPA implementation are you using? and why have you omitted provider from the persistence.xml? and why are some Hibernate jars in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Whell, i am suspicious from this hibernate error, and i see in the wildlfy documentation [link] (http://blog.arungupta.me/java-ee-7-implementations-in-wildfly-tech-tip-3/) and really it uses Hibernate for java api persistence. I search on the web, e find many different providers, and i confuse with it, how i can search for the correct provider to use? and i need to import some dependency, take in mind if wildfly use the hibernate implementation?

Comment: You can use ANY JPA provider with any JavaEE provider, just specify the "provider" tag in your persistence.xml (and put the jars in the CLASSPATH) ... for the version of JPA that the JavaEE provider supports. And which one are you WANTING to use?

Comment: i'm doing for learning JPA, can use hibernate. i try to put `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` on persistence.xml and put **hibernate-entitymanager** and **hibernate-core** in the pom.xml, but the error persists.

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml?

Comment: yes, i edit the question amd put the pom.xml file.

Comment: and you think hibernate-core v3.3 goes with hibernate-entitymanager v5 ? Perhaps revisit their documentation ...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be due to declaring inconsistent dependencies - hibernate-entitymanager in version [5.0.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-entitymanager%7C5.0.0.Final%7Cjar) requires hibernate-core 5.0.0, but you force to use hibernate-core in version 3.3.0.SP1. The class `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy` does not exist in version 3.3.0.SP1. As hibernate-entitymanager declares transitive dependency on hibernate-core, you can just remove the dependency on hibernate-core.

Furthermore, Wildfly 8 already includes hibernate (version 4.3), as it must provide Java EE functionality by specification. You may just use hibernate on Wildfly, which is more standard, unless you don't require special features of hibernate 5.0. In that case remove also hibernate-entitymanager dependency from pom.xml and your code should still work.

Comment: works with hibernate **4.3.10.Final** version, and another thing, my **persistence.xml** was in another project, the dependency is correct, but works only with persistence.xml in the same Orm project.